# How to replace specific characters of a string with tab in R

Tags: regex, string, r

Having a data frame with a string in each row, I need to replace n'th character into tab. Moreover, there are an inconstant number of spaces before m'th character that I need to convert to tab as well. 
For instance having following row:

```
"00001 000     0 John                                                      Smith"
```

I need to replace the 6th character (space) into tab and replace the spaces between John and Smith into tab as well. For all the rows the last word (Smith) starts from 75th character. So, basically I need to replace all spaces before 78th character into tab.

I need the above row as follows:

```
"00001<Tab>000     0 John<Tab>Smith"
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: For your future reference, you can search for R-tag questions in the SO search bar, like this: `[r] replace with tab`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Actually, I already visited the page you mentioned. Using that solution, I would replace some spaces that I do not want (like spaces before "John") as well.

Comment: @hwnd Yes exactly. Just printing the "df" I got tab symbol instead of tab in the string.Also I get unwanted tabs for the rows which have more words as surname. So, if the surname is "Smith Smith" I do not want any tabs between them.

Comment: @user30314 My bad -- I should have read this more carefully. I'll ask someone else to reopen this.

Comment: Should a sequence of ten consecutive spaces (e.g.) become ten tabs or one tab?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien no just one tab. In fact I want to save the final result as a tab delimited file. This is why I want to make this conversion.

Comment: Can you edit and write out the exact output you want but with <TAB> as a tab char, preserving any spaces you want preserved?

Comment: Are your files in a fixed-width format? Maybe look at `read.fwf` for the correct way to read them in

Comment: And do you mean the last name starts on the 75th character? It seems to in your sample.

Comment: @MrFlick yes sorry. And I checked the data frame. Unfortunately it does not follow the fixed-width files for the third column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `gsub` here.

```
x <- c('00001 000     0 John                                                      Smith',
       '00002 000     1 Josh                                                      Black',
       '00003 000     2 Jane                                                      Smith',
       '00004 000     3 Jeff                                                      Smith')

x <- gsub("(?<=[0-9]{5}) |(?<!\\d) +(?=(?i:[a-z]))", "\t", x, perl=T)
```

Output

```
[1] "00001\t000     0 John\tSmith" "00002\t000     1 Josh\tBlack"
[3] "00003\t000     2 Jane\tSmith" "00004\t000     3 Jeff\tSmith"
```

To actually see the `\t` in output use `cat(x)`

```
00001   000     0 John  Smith
00002   000     1 Josh  Black 
00003   000     2 Jane  Smith 
00004   000     3 Jeff  Smith
```

Comment: @user30314 You should be aware that this relies on the final two columns being the only adjacent pair of non-numeric columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution if it always starts at 75. First some sample data

```
#sample data
a <- "00001 000     0 John                                                      Smith"
b <- "00001 000     0 John                                                      Smith"
```

Now since you know positions, i'll use `substr`. To extract the parts, then i'll trim the middle, then you can paste in the tabs.

```
#extract parts
part1<-substr(c(a,b), 1, 5)
part2<-gsub("\\s*$","",substr(c(a,b), 7, 74))
part3<-substr(c(a,b), 75, 10000L)

#add in tabs
paste(part1, part2, part3, sep="\t")
```

Comment: For some reasons, I got unwanted spaces before the surname in "part3".

Comment: @user30314 Well, apparently the last section doesn't start at 75. There must be some order hidden in your data.